Remove last word from each string in grouped data prior ro exporting as txt file
I have a very large file containing more than one million names. I need to separate this file into several smaller files of 15000 names. I need to use the names in a search string, thus, each species name must be surrounded by "" and separated by OR.
I have managed to do this, and made a code that splits my data into more than 100 smaller files, and exports them into txt format.
The output files look like below, each containing 15000 names:
"Apotomopterus conjunctus" OR "Apotomopterus tongbiguanicus" OR "Apotomopterus piriformis" OR "Apotomopterus artemis" OR "Carabus koyamai" OR
What I want is to remove the final OR before exporting the txt files, so that the last entry is a species name in quotation marks.
"Apotomopterus conjunctus" OR "Apotomopterus tongbiguanicus" OR "Apotomopterus piriformis" OR "Apotomopterus artemis" OR "Carabus koyamai"
However, I am unable to write a code that removes the final OR.
I have created a reproducible example with a datset of similar format to mine, but with far fever names. I have inserted the code I use to split and export my data.
set.seed(1)
spe <- as.data.frame(stringi::stri_rand_strings(100, 5))
colnames(spe) <- "Species"
spe$OR <- "OR"
spe$species <- paste(spe$Species, spe$OR)

species <- as.data.frame(spe$species) #My true data contains more than 1 million entries

n = 10 #number of names per file (in my data, n = 15000 but that should make no difference)

species %>% group_by(row_number() %/% n) 
%>% group_walk(~ write.table(.x, paste0("insecta species names_", .y, ".txt"), 
quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, eol = " ", sep = ","))

I have tried the following options with no luck:
species %>% group_by(row_number() %/% n) %>% gsub('.{2}$', '') %>% group_walk(~ write.table(.x, paste0("insecta species names_", .y, ".txt"), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, eol = " ", sep = ","))

species %>% group_by(row_number() %/% n) %>% substring(- 2) %>% group_walk(~ write.table(.x, paste0("insecta species names_", .y, ".txt"), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, eol = " ", sep = ","))

species %>% group_by(row_number() %/% n) %>% substr(species,1,nchar(species)-2) %>% group_walk(~ write.table(.x, paste0("insecta species names_", .y, ".txt"), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, eol = " ", sep = ","))


Instead of having a separate column for "OR", we can paste the text "OR" using collapse argument.
set.seed(1)
spe <- data.frame(Species = stringi::stri_rand_strings(100, 5))

n = 10

purrr::iwalk(
  split(spe$Species, ceiling(seq_along(spe$Species)/n)), 
  \(.x, .y)  write.table(paste(.x, collapse = " OR "), 
                paste0("insecta species names_", .y, ".txt"), quote = FALSE, 
                row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, eol = " ", sep = ","))


Thank you, this solved my problem perfectly!
